# python related with strings

Tags: python, string

Accept a string as input. If the input string is of odd length, then continue with it. If the input string is of even length, make the string of odd length by following the two steps mentioned below:
(1) If the last character is a period (.), then remove it
(2) If the last character is not a period, then add a period (.) to the end of the string

Call this string of odd length word. Select a substring made up of three consecutive characters from word such that there are an equal number of characters to the left and right of this substring. Print this substring as output. You can assume that all input strings will be in lower case and will have a length of at least four.

Above is the question so the code i wrote for this is:

```
string=str(input())
n=len(string)
if n%2!=0:
    print(string[n//2-1:n//2+2])
else:
    if string[n-1]=='.':
        string=string[0:n-1]
    
    else:
        string=string + '.'

    print(string[n//2-1:n//2+2])
```

so when i take case 1 it is right when string is odd but when i take case 2 and string is even then it gets converted to odd by line 7 but when we print new string by same function it gives one value ahead.
Please help me in this

[test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz2Mc.png)

[test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz2Mc.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You assigned `n=len(string)` in line 2 only.

To solve the question, you can do an update (`n=len(string)`) afterwards as stated below

```
string = input()
n = len(string)

if n % 2 == 0:
    if string[-1] == '.':
        string = string[:-1]
    else:
        string += '.'

n = len(string)  # update n to the length of the modified string

print(string[n//2-1:n//2+2])
```

Hope my answer is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string in 2 parts first:

```
val = str(input("your string?"))

def split_str(val):
    first = val[: len(val) // 2]
    second = val[len(val) // 2 :]
    return (first, second)

def not_even(val):
    first, second = split_str(val)
    if len(first)+1 == len(second):
        print(f'{first[-1]}{second[:2]}')
    else:
        first, second = split_str(val)
        if second[-1] == '.':
            val = val.replace(".","")
            not_even(val)
        if second[-1] != '.':
            val = val+'.'
            not_even(val)
            
not_even(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input string length is at least 4 (you should really validate this) then:

```
ustr = input('Enter a value: ')

if len(ustr) % 2 == 0:
    if ustr[-1] == '.':
        ustr = ustr[:-1]
    else:
        ustr += '.'

i = (len(ustr) - 3) // 2

print(ustr[i:i+3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letter = str(input("enter a input value\n"))
n = len(letter)
if n%2 == 0:
    if letter[-1] == '.':
        letter = letter[:-1]
    else:
        letter = letter+'.'

n =int((len(letter)-1)/2) #for three consecutive character
print(letter[n-1:n+2])
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.